# gmail android application gradient background

Tags: android, background, gmail, drawable, gradient

How can I obtain the gradient or from where could I download a bitmap as gmail application has in the background? I know that I could use some drawing tools and make it by myself but I would like to find exactly the same drawable. I have been searching online and through the android Sdk resources and can't find this drawable. I also notice that this background appeared when I created a new project as a default background for the activity but unfortunately I don't remember what settings did I set then and now when I create a new project there is just a standard white background.

[image]

Comment: My Gmail app doesn't have a gradient background.  Are you using stock Android or a custom ROM or manufacturer skin?

Comment: I'm using manufacturer skin but also running GO Launcher EX

Comment: I turned off the launcher and set default options and gmail background is still present

Comment: To be more specific it's not a real radiant gradient but it looks like the halves of ellipse that overlap each other

Comment: @MarcinS. Can you make a screenshot, mark the gradient on the picture and post it here?

Comment: Sure. I have taken a picture from the real device. Quality is poor but you should be able to see what kind of background it is